# AttributeError: module 'hello.views' has no attribute 'index' in Django while trying to create a helloWorld page

Tags: python, django

so I have been trying to follow the CS Harvard course thing but I'm stuck on lesson three lmao. they are using django to make a website I think? and I've run into this problem because I'm copying exactly what the instructor is doing but i still cant make my other part show up.

What its supposed to do is have the basic website IP thing and then if i add /hello it should say hello world but it doesnt.

The only files ive changed are these

```py
# urls.py in lecture3
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path #added import include and path hello line
urlpatterns = [
path('hello/', include("hello.urls")),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

# urls.py in hello
from django.urls import path
from hello import views
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index")
]

# views.py in hello
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

and then in settings.py, the only line i added was

```
'hello',
```

inside of the installed apps part.

and the error message i keep on getting is File

> "/Users/matc/Dev/cfehome/lecture3/hello/urls.py", line 7, in 
> path("", views.index, name="index") AttributeError: module 'hello.views' has no attribute 'index'

any help would be greatly recommended!

Answer (score 1):

I also found that in the views.py of the app:

```py
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

There should be a space between `index` and `(request):`. I.e. `def index (request):`.

Answer (score 0):

I Think You have created a django project named lecture3,
Fine,
**You have to create the following Configuration then your app will run perfectly**

**in urls.py of your root directory(lectur3)**
Add Following Code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', include('hello.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Then You should add you app in installed app of your **settings.py** file
like:-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'hello',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

**urls.py in hello**

```
from django.urls import path

from hello import views

urlpatterns = [

path("", views.index, name="index")

]
```

**views.py in hello**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

**Now run your Server By**

```
python manage.py runserver
```

**Your app will run successfully**
at this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/
```

Comment: hey thank you! this worked for the django script!! could you tell me where I went wrong and what you changed though? the only think i see that you changed was in URLpatters you did 'hello' instead of "hello". Thanks again!!!